# pandas multiindex set_labels

Tags: pandas, label, multi-index

I have a pandas multiindex like this one

```
result.index

MultiIndex(levels=[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35], [1, 6, 12, 17, 18, 21, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 64, 66, 67, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74]],
           labels=[[10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14], [17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27]],
           names=['ref', None])
```

And I want to change the second label by this one

```
new_label
[-0.9, -0.85, -0.8, -0.75, -0.7, -0.65, -0.6, -0.55, -0.5, -0.45, -0.4, -0.9, -0.85, -0.8, -0.75, -0.7, -0.65, -0.6, -0.55, -0.5, -0.45, -0.4, -0.9, -0.85, -0.8, -0.75, -0.7, -0.65, -0.6, -0.55, -0.5, -0.45, -0.4, -0.9, -0.85, -0.8, -0.75, -0.7, -0.65, -0.6, -0.55, -0.5, -0.45, -0.4, -0.9, -0.85, -0.8, -0.75, -0.7, -0.65, -0.6, -0.55, -0.5, -0.45, -0.4]
```

so the result should be

```
result.index

    MultiIndex(levels=[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35], [1, 6, 12, 17, 18, 21, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 64, 66, 67, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74]],
               labels=[[10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14], [-0.9, -0.85, -0.8, -0.75, -0.7, -0.65, -0.6, -0.55, -0.5, -0.45, -0.4, -0.9, -0.85, -0.8, -0.75, -0.7, -0.65, -0.6, -0.55, -0.5, -0.45, -0.4, -0.9, -0.85, -0.8, -0.75, -0.7, -0.65, -0.6, -0.55, -0.5, -0.45, -0.4, -0.9, -0.85, -0.8, -0.75, -0.7, -0.65, -0.6, -0.55, -0.5, -0.45, -0.4, -0.9, -0.85, -0.8, -0.75, -0.7, -0.65, -0.6, -0.55, -0.5, -0.45, -0.4]],
               names=['ref', None])
```

I tried with

```
result.index.set_labels(labels=new_label,level=1)
```

But instead I get this

```
MultiIndex(levels=[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35], [1, 6, 12, 17, 18, 21, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 64, 66, 67, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74]],
           labels=[[10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]],
           names=['wnd dir ref', None])
```

The labels are fulfilled with 0

What is wrong or missing?

Answer (score 2):

If want use `set_label` need same types, here integers (it seems bug):

```
#test if working with integers
mux1 = mux.set_labels((np.array(new_label) * 100).astype(int), level=1)
print (mux1)

MultiIndex(levels=[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35], [1, 6, 12, 17, 18, 21, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 64, 66, 67, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74]],
           labels=[[10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14], [-90, -85, -80, -75, -70, -65, -60, -55, -50, -45, -40, -90, -85, -80, -75, -70, -65, -60, -55, -50, -45, -40, -90, -85, -80, -75, -70, -65, -60, -55, -50, -45, -40, -90, -85, -80, -75, -70, -65, -60, -55, -50, -45, -40, -90, -85, -80, -75, -70, -65, -60, -55, -50, -45, -40]],
           names=['ref', None])
```

---

```
mux = pd.MultiIndex(levels=[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35], [1, 6, 12, 17, 18, 21, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 64, 66, 67, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74]],
           labels=[[10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14], [17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27]],
           names=['ref', None])

df = pd.DataFrame([0] * 55, index=mux, columns=['a'])
```

Possible solution is [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) for new 3 level MultiIndex and remove second one by [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df = df.set_index([new_label], append=True).reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
```

Or create new MultiIndex:

```
df.index = [df.index.get_level_values(0), new_label]
print (df.head(10))
           a
ref         
10  -0.90  0
    -0.85  0
    -0.80  0
    -0.75  0
    -0.70  0
    -0.65  0
    -0.60  0
    -0.55  0
    -0.50  0
    -0.45  0
```

Also if need set `MultiIndex` names:

```
df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df.index.get_level_values(0), 
                                      new_label], names=('ref','new'))
print (df.head(10))
           a
ref new     
10  -0.90  0
    -0.85  0
    -0.80  0
    -0.75  0
    -0.70  0
    -0.65  0
    -0.60  0
    -0.55  0
    -0.50  0
    -0.45  0
```